How to link Raylib with hot reloading in C++ (Windows + Linux platforms)
Context
I am making a game in C++ (I am fairly new to the language) and have been using the Raylib library to handle things like windowing code, I am trying to get a very basic hot reloading test working where I have split my game code (currently just drawing a rectangle and the current framerate) to a file that is exported as a dynamic library and then linked to the driver code which creates the executable.
main.cpp:
#include "raylib.h"
#include "platform.cpp"

int screenWidth = 1920;
int screenHeight = 1080;

int main() {
    GameAPI gameAPI = {};
    GameLib gameLib = LoadGameLibrary(&gameAPI);
    if (gameLib == nullptr) {
        TraceLog(LOG_ERROR, "Could not load game API");
        return -1;
    }
    Game* game = gameAPI.createGame();
    if (!game) {
        TraceLog(LOG_ERROR, "Could not create game!");
        FreeGameLibrary(gameLib);
        return -1;
    }
    InitWindow(screenWidth, screenHeight, "Raylib");
  
    // Main game loop
    while (!WindowShouldClose()) {
        BeginDrawing();
        ClearBackground(WHITE);
        if (IsWindowReady()) {
          gameAPI.updateGame(game);
        } else {
          TraceLog(LOG_ERROR, "Window not ready!");
        }
        EndDrawing();
    }

    gameAPI.destroyGame(game);
    FreeGameLibrary(gameLib);
}

I have created a basic platform file to handle different operating systems (just Linux and Windows for now), this handles loading the library for different operating systems and their different ways of getting function pointers, loading the library, etc. I have testing that it works and correctly finds all the function pointers and properly loads the library, only when I have an the update function external does anything fail.
// platform.hpp
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define NOGDI             // All GDI defines and routines
    #define NOUSER            // All USER defines and routines
    #undef near
    #undef far


  #define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
  #include "Windows.h"
  typedef HMODULE GameLib;
#else
  #include <dlfcn.h>
  typedef void* GameLib;
#endif

#include "game.hpp"

typedef Game* (*CreateGameFunc)();
typedef void (*UpdateGameFunc)(Game*);
typedef void (*DestroyGameFunc)(Game*);

struct GameAPI {
  CreateGameFunc createGame;
  UpdateGameFunc updateGame;
  DestroyGameFunc destroyGame;
};

GameLib LoadGameLibrary(GameAPI* gameAPI);
void FreeGameLibrary(void* gameLib);

// platform.cpp
#include "platform.hpp"
#ifdef _WIN32
GameLib LoadGameLibrary(GameAPI* gameAPI) {
    GameLib gameLib = (GameLib) LoadLibraryA("game.dll");
    if (!gameLib) {
        // Handle error
        return nullptr;
    }
  
    gameAPI->createGame = (CreateGameFunc)GetProcAddress(gameLib, "CreateGame");
    gameAPI->updateGame = (UpdateGameFunc)GetProcAddress(gameLib, "UpdateGame");
    gameAPI->destroyGame = (DestroyGameFunc)GetProcAddress(gameLib, "DestroyGame");
    if (!gameAPI->createGame || !gameAPI->updateGame || !gameAPI->destroyGame) {
      return nullptr;
    } else {
      return gameLib;
    }
}

void FreeGameLibrary(GameLib gameLib) {
    FreeLibrary(gameLib);
}

Finally, my game code is written to be exported as a dynamic library using some defines to ensure function names aren't mangled and are exported properly on windows this is compiled separately then linked to the main executable above as shown in the CMakeLists.txt below this code block:
The crash is occurring at Game::update() as soon as any Raylib functions that are used for drawing to the screen are called.
game.hpp:
#ifndef GAME_HPP
#define GAME_HPP

#define EXTERNAL extern "C"

#ifdef _WIN32
  #ifdef GAME_EXPORTS
    #define GAME_API __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define GAME_API __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif
#else
  #define GAME_API
#endif

EXTERNAL class GAME_API Game {
public:
    void Update();
};

EXTERNAL GAME_API Game* CreateGame();
EXTERNAL GAME_API void DestroyGame(Game* game);
EXTERNAL GAME_API void UpdateGame(Game* game);
#endif // GAME_HPP

// game.cpp
void Game::Update() {
    // Update logic that uses Raylib functions
    // At this point IsWindowReady() return false for some reason?
    DrawFPS(10, 10);
    DrawRectangle(100, 100, 200, 200, GREEN);
}
// Macro to export using __declspec(dllexport) extern "C"
EXTERNAL void UpdateGame(Game *game) {
    game->Update();
}

..
// Other start + end functions that do not cause crash/not relevant

As I said before I am using CMake to build this project where I use add_library(game SHARED src/game.cpp) to build the game.cpp file as a library and link raylib to both using the PRIVATE flag
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24) # FetchContent is available in 3.11+
project(Raylib)

if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Darwin")
  error("MacOS is not supported")
endif()

# Generate compile_commands.json
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "") # works
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
# Dependencies
set(RAYLIB_VERSION 5.0)
find_package(raylib ${RAYLIB_VERSION} QUIET) # QUIET or REQUIRED
if (NOT raylib_FOUND) # If there's none, fetch and build raylib
  include(FetchContent)
  FetchContent_Declare(
    raylib
    DOWNLOAD_EXTRACT_TIMESTAMP OFF
    URL https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/archive/refs/tags/${RAYLIB_VERSION}.tar.gz
  )
  FetchContent_GetProperties(raylib)
  if (NOT raylib_POPULATED) # Have we downloaded raylib yet?
    set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET YES)
    FetchContent_Populate(raylib)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
    add_subdirectory(${raylib_SOURCE_DIR} ${raylib_BINARY_DIR})
  endif()
endif()

if (CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME STREQUAL "Windows")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/um\"")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/shared\"")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.22621.0/ucrt\"")
  if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/raylib.dll")
    file(COPY ${raylib_BINARY_DIR}/raylib/raylib.dll DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  endif()
else()
  if (NOT EXISTS "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/raylib.so")
    file(COPY ${raylib_BINARY_DIR}/raylib/raylib.so DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
  endif()
endif()

# Project
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ./src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE raylib)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Game dynamic library for hot reloading
add_library(game SHARED ./src/game.cpp)
target_compile_definitions(game PRIVATE GAME_EXPORTS)
target_link_libraries(game PRIVATE raylib)
# Custom target to build only the game library
add_custom_target(game_only
  DEPENDS game
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target game
)

Problem:
So far the project compiles and links successfully, however as soon as it starts, a windows opens briefly before immediately crashing as soon as gameAPI.updateGame(game) is called (it encounters a memory access violation upon trying to reference the internal Raylib RLGL pointer). After further testing I have found that IsWindowReady() returns false at this point suggesting that Raylib may be being double included and I do not understand why as it is built as using the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag and linked to both the game library and the main executable at the same time.
Disclaimer
Please note this is my first time using C++ for a more complex project and most of this has been me learning things like linking and CMake for the first time and so I may just be being ignorant of some flag I need.
Thanks in advance.

If you want to load different implementations at runtime, I don't think you should be linking with the DLL at all. Load and unload the DLLs at runtime only.

what does the title have to do with the question ? does the error happen only when hot-reloading ? also how is Game class declared in the header and cpp file ?

Yes the problem only occurs when trying to call the update game function via a function pointer loaded from a library and I have just added the header for the game class now, it was being flagged as spam when I tried to post before

What happens if you do not link with the DLLs that you load at runtime? I've never tried mixing linking with runtime loading of the same DLL. Perhaps it's supposed to work, but it seems wrong to me.

@TedLyngmo I am not sure I understand what you mean by not linking with the DLL, as not linking caused a linker error as the exported functions are unresolved symbols, and I load the game library at runtime just before opening the window.

"the Game class functions are unresolved symbols" - So, it is not using the symbols that you load at runtime. You need to show how you load the DLL. Are you using GetProcAddress to get the addresses of the functions in the DLL or did you just leave that part out?

I am using GetProcAddress to find the function pointers, but it seemed to be finding the function pointers, I had not included the code as I didn't think it was relevant - I just edited the question to show the DLL loading

well, the code above only loads that dll on startup then never really unloads it (because LoadLibraryA is reference counted), so the error is likely not from the "hot reloading part" (which doesn't work, but won't crash your application), are you statically or dynamically linking raylib ?

@AhmedAEK
I was just trying to ensure everything worked and just try to at least load the dll once, and once I had that working I was going to change it to reload on a keypress but had been caught up with the current problem. I think I am linking statically - I am using target_link_libraries(game PRIVATE raylib) and target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE raylib) to ensure it compiles - I think this is where my problem is but I just do not know enough about this to be sure

If you really want runtime loading / unloading of the DLLs, you need to use the function pointers you get from GetProcAddress, so I'd start by not linking with the DLLs you aim to load at runtime. At least then it becomes clear when you have no link-time dependencies left.

Here's an example of how I've done loading of two DLLs: https://godbolt.org/z/bWrG4bnhE . I then use instances of DLLkernel32 and DLLuser32 and call the functions via their member variables that are function pointers.

I just realised I had not been using the function pointers for some calls and instead directly calling the exported functions which was why I had a linker error and so I have now got the project to compile without linking the dll and then loading at runtime, however the crash still persists, your example is quite similar to my GameAPI struct which also has the function pointers as members - I have update the example to reflect this

The cast in GameLib gameLib = (GameLib) LoadLibraryA("game.dll"); is utterly confusing. I thought you did something wrong there, but GameLib seems to be a typedef for HMODULE. Don't cast there.

Turns out that the BUILD_SHARED_LIBS flag in my CMake was set to off for some reason, after changing it and copying the raylib.dll file both the main executable and the game.dll are properly sharing their raylib context which was the problem, thanks for the help, this was the first time I have had to deal with DLLs so I was getting confused at what was considered 'good' and what I actually needed to do resulting on a lot of unecessary stuff in this project

Turns out I was not compiling the Raylib library as a shared library causing there to be two raylib contexts with only one being initialised, I fixed this by setting BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to ON in my CMake file
